# [FromBody]List<BlogUser> items How to rewrite by ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage ProcessChecked([FromBody]List<BlogUser> items)
{ }
```

I can not support it by ServiceStack, How can I write the code?

Answer (score 1):

Every Service in ServiceStack needs to be defined with a single concrete Request DTO. To [define a Request DTO that accepts a collection of Types](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Batched-Requests#defining-a-request-dto-to-accept-a-collection-of-types) you can inherit from `List<T>`, e.g:

```
public class UpdateBlogUsers : List<BlogUser> {}

public object Put(UpdateBlogUsers request)
{
    //....
}
```